# Top level domain's cookie masks the subdomain's cookie in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

After signing in, it goes to the correct url (with the matching subdomain), but I still see "Sign Up" or "Sign in" instead of "Logged in as xxx" and "Sign out", meaning the `user_signed_in?` returns false (current_user is not set).

Here's the application_controller.rb:

```
private  
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    logger.info root_url(subdomain: current_user.username)
    logger.info user_signed_in?
    root_url(subdomain: current_user.username)
  end
```

`user_signed_in?` returns `true` here.

The home_controller.rb to which it gets redirected:

```
def show
  logger.info user_signed_in?
  @user = User.find_by_username!(request.subdomain)
end
```

whereas here `user_signed_in?` returns `false`.

The routes file:

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  match '/' => 'home#show', as: :user
end

root :to => 'home#welcome'
```

As Arun has said in the comments, the problem, I discovered was with 2 cookies of same name, but one for top-level domain and the other for the subdomain.

Is there any way to delete only one cookie or not set it at all? I tried `reset_session`, but it deleted both the cookies.

Comment: Check the browser cookie. My assumption is its creating two cookies one is with subdomain another one is without subdomain. So app is confused in accessing the correct session.

Comment: Hi Arun, yes there are 2 cookies of same name, one with subdomain and one without. Could you please clarify why it is happening and how to overcome it?

Comment: I didn't find any good solution. Its happening because your login page is under top domain and your show page(after login) is under subdomain. So its creating session for top domain as well as subdomain.

Comment: I changed the session store to ActiveRecord::SessionStore and ran the migration. But no entries were made as I moved around the app. Weird!